# Records with identical uid and timestamp in node_revision

Tags: database, nodes

I'm investigating an issue on a D7 site where a handful of node revisions have apparently gone missing. The issue was discovered on 3/5, and I just noticed in my node_revision table that several records were created on 3/4 with the same uid and the same timestamp (1362422613). How is this possible? Might it indicate a MySQL problem?

Answer (score 0):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a Drupal Developer, just a pure MySQL DBA

Here is a sample `node_revision` table:

```
mysql> show create table node_revisions\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: node_revisions
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `node_revisions` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `teaser` longtext NOT NULL,
  `log` longtext NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `format` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=227825 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Strictly in terms of MySQL, there is nothing in place to prevent the same UID and timestamp from entering this table multiple times. The index `uid` is a non-unique index on the `uid` column. What you need is a UNIQUE INDEX to prevent this at the database level.

Run this query:

```
SELECT uid,timestamp,COUNT(1) ut_dups FROM node_revisions
GROUP BY uid,timestamp HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

and this will uncover other UIDs with the same timestamp issue.

If you want to block rows from entering this table with duplicate `(uid,timestamp)`, change the indexes as follows (making a backup first):

```
#
# Backup node_revision
#
CREATE TABLE node_revision_backup LIKE node_revision;
INSERT INTO node_revision_backup SELECT * FROM node_revision;
#
# Change Indexes
#
CREATE TABLE node_revision_new LIKE node_revision;
ALTER TABLE node_revision_new DROP INDEX uid;
ALTER TABLE node_revision_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX uniq_uid_timestamp (uid,timestamp);
INSERT IGNORE INTO node_revision_new SELECT * FROM node_revision;
DROP TABLE node_revision;
ALTER TABLE node_revision_new RENAME node_revision;
```

The UNIQUE INDEX `uniq_uid_timestamp` physically prevents `(uid,timestamp)` from appearing more than once. Check the contents of `node_revision` and make sure it is proper.

If it looks good, you could run:

```
DROP TABLE node_revision_backup;
```

or keep the backup.

If it does not look good, run this:

```
ALTER TABLE node_revision RENAME node_revision_old;
ALTER TABLE node_revision_backup RENAME node_revision;
DROP TABLE node_revision_old;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

You will need to check all modules involved that writes to the `node_revision` table.